# Aggregated template specialisation between convertible types

Tags: c++, templates

Consider these template classes:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
  T m_t;
public:
  A(T t):m_t(t){};
};

template <typename T, typename D>
class B{
  A<D> m_a;
  T m_t;
public:
  B(T t, A<D> a):m_t(t),m_a(a){};
};
```

This will of course work:
`A<int> a{1};`
.

This will also work because implicit conversion:
`A<int> a{'e'};`

But this will not :

```
A<char> a{'e'}
B<int,int> b(1,a)
```

Is there any workaround this? I would expect implicit conversion between char and int when instantiating B class.

Answer (score 1):

`A<char>` and `A<int>` are two completely independent classes. But you can always add a corresponding converting constructor into the `A` template:

```
template <typename U>
A(A<U> a) : m_t(a.m_t) { }

template <typename U> friend class A;
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xejPz5KM9

Note that you need to provide access to the private member `m_t` to all instances of `A` by that `friend` declaration. Otherwise, `A<U>` won't be generally able to access `A<T>.m_t`.